# What is the default values of ServerLimit in apache 2.4.6 if we don't specify the values in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, rhel7

My httpd.conf file has no values set for MPM parameter. What will be the default values. I'm using RHEL7 with apache 2.4.6.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what MPM is used. Can see the results from search for `DEFAULT_SERVER_LIMIT` in Apache source code.

- https://github.com/apache/httpd/search?q=DEFAULT_SERVER_LIMIT&unscoped_q=DEFAULT_SERVER_LIMIT